# How do I use a remote shutter trigger and radio flash triggers simultaneously?

Tags: yongnuo, remote, wireless-triggers, wireless-flash, shutter-release

I would like to shoot my Fuji X-T2 with Flashpoint remote shutter release and off-camera Yongnuo flashes and radio transmitters (622 series). I also have a YN600EX-RT I could link in. All components are compatible with my camera in manual flash mode, but not sure how to set this up. (Doing wildlife photography at night and need to have camera close to action without being too close myself.) Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the 622s as your shutter release? Or thinking of using a motion sensor?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, just set up the shutter releases and the flash triggers the way you normally do. They shouldn't interfere with each other.

But you can also just do this with YN-622 triggers, if you have YN-622s and a YN-622-TX.

The most typical way you use flash radio triggers as a shutter remote release is to cable the receiver to the shutter cable release port of the camera, and use the transmitter in-hand as your remote with the TEST button.  Some may even allow for half-pressing the TEST button as a half-press on the shutter button.

To do both remote shutter and wireless flash triggering at the same time, you typically need two separate Tx/Rx sets, set to different channels. But some systems can have one unit be both the on-camera receiver for the shutter and the flash transmitter on the hotshoe.

With the 622s, you use a YN-622C *transceiver* as your in-hand remote, you set C.Fn.02 on the YN-622-TX to ON (so it can be a shutter release), you put it on the camera and cable its 2.5mm sync port to your camera's shutter release (if you're putting it on a post-2012 Canon body, you don't need to do the cable, the flash hotshoe itself acts as the cable release port; but as you're using a Fuji body, you'll have to use the cable).  Now the TEST button on the in-hand YN-622 is your shutter release.

You will need a 2.5mm to Fuji shutter release cable if you don't have one. Searching for Pixel or Vello will probably find you one.